# Switch load using toggle switch or switch button

Tags: load, toggle-switch

The fact is after designing my own dc-dc converter (0.8v-20.5v 5A max) I decided to add a switch load button in order to connect/disconnect the load only after setting my desired voltage.

I could use a simple toggle switch button but generally their bounce enough on the first 100ms so that why I want to search for another design.

I've been searching some implementations but all of them uses an n-channel mosfet that's for me its perfect, but the problem is at voltages like 0.8v-3v the design is not suitable due to mosfet gate voltage minimum.

I want to make an implementation like this kind of button in keysight power supply
[image]

What I need is when voltage is at 0.8v for example if I turn on the toggle switch, output voltage be 0.8v and so on.

Its important that the implementation be capable of handling 5-6A.

Comment: Try a push button with a cap to debounce  to a D FF toggle with power on reset. Then a high side switch IC use any logic level devices.

Comment: Hi Tony. Is there any web page I can look at, for an implementation like you propose?. Thanks so much!

Comment: @marcosbc A typical high side switch at about your current compliance (but perhaps not quite) is this [TI IC](https://www.ti.com/lit//ds/symlink/tps2557.pdf). You could use that in conjunction with a relay, too, if you wanted. You'd activate both of them at the same time, allow some small delay long enough for the relay to settle down, and then disable the IC switch. That's the kind of approach I'd probably take here. You can even work out a trapezoidal power-on current ramp, if you wanted, with that IC.

Comment: @jonk It's interesting what you propose. High side switches commonly not have such low voltages inputs like 0.8v.

Comment: @marcosbc That device is somewhere between \$660\:\text{mV}\$ and \$1.1\:\text{V}\$ for the enable input. Perhaps not perfect for your stated needs. But it is in the ballpark. I also prefer having a genuine relay engaged when supplying power and to remove the semiconductors from the direct power delivery equation as soon as possible.

Comment: It is wiser to use suitable logic levels with an LDO off the input voltage, not the output of 0.8

Comment: At the risk of sounding like a jerk, I want to let you know that using "wanna" sounds unprofessional. I would avoid that in technical writing. This seems common in ESL learners so I don't think it's your fault, the rest of your writing seems fine.

Comment: @ellliot thanks so much for the suggestion. I already edit my post in order to enhance the content.